# how to factor $f(x)=x^4-7x^2+1$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, factoring

How do you factor this equation?  I have tried to use factoring method where the expanded b term factors add to B and multiply to get C.

Comment: Hint: rewrite it as $(x^4 + 2x^2 + 1) - 9x^2$.

Comment: *Hint:*  Let's name a new variable $u$ and let $u=x^2$.  We have now $u^2-7u+1$ instead of your original expression, which should now be more easily handled.  Once you've factored in terms of $u$, you may then take put $u$ back in terms of $x$ and continue from there.

Comment: I think it would be reasonable for down-voters to explain their actions. The OP has mentioned his efforts.

Comment: @Brian Please research how to solve quadratics and show us what you've tried. Any major technique should be useful and I'm sure you can find some resources online.

Comment: @DaveRadcliffe's hint also  follows if you first note that the polynomial is [palindromic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial), then write it in terms of $\,x + 1/x\,$ as $\,f(x)=x^2\left(x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\color{red}{+2-2}-7\right) = x^2\left(\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2-9\right) = \ldots$.

Comment: What are the b B and C??

Comment: @JohnMa I would guess the OP was referring to the [\[a-\]b-c method](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52878.html) a.k.a. the [ac method](https://people.richland.edu/james/misc/acmeth.html).

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to see that $x^4-7x^2+1$ has no rational roots. So if it factors (over the integers), it can only do so as the product of two quadratics.  Since the lead and constant coefficients are both $1$ and there are no terms of odd degree, the factorization must be of the form $(x^2+bx+\sigma)(x^2-bx+\sigma)$ with $\sigma=\pm1$.  We have

$$(x^2+bx+\sigma)(x^2-bx+\sigma)=x^4+(2\sigma-b^2)x^2+1$$

so we need $2\sigma-b^2=-7$, which rewrites as $b^2=7+2\sigma$.  Letting $\sigma=1$ gives $b=\pm3$, so we have the factorization

$$x^4-7x^2+1=(x^2+3x+1)(x^2-3x+1)$$

Note, the other option, $\sigma=-1$, gives another valid factorization, just not over the integers:

$$x^4-7x^2+1=(x^2+\sqrt5x-1)(x^2-\sqrt5x-1)$$